# Interpolation of uneven data in 2D using Gaussian Process

Tags: gaussian-process, interpolation

I have a dataset that is spacially distributed like the figure below. The function values of each point is plotted as the elevation in the 3rd dimension.

Now, I want to find a kernel/and or method that interpolates this area. By looking at the function it is pretty clear to us humans that there should be high values running along the vertical direction to the far left of the data set (along the arrow).

[image]

But using the standard kernels of GP (RBF, RationalQuadratic, Matern) they all give results similarly to the figure below.

[image]

The resulting values in between the spikes are way lower than I would desire. By letting the length scale be different in each dimension I can get a little closer.

[image]

However I see two problems with this. First of all, it is coordinate dependent, meaning that if I would rotate the coordinate system, or have the spikes going diagonally, it would give a worse result. Secondly, the length scale is affected at the hole area which leads to false smooshing in the vertical direction over the hole domain. In the long term I would like the solution to be applicable to a data set that is even more unordered, i.e. the horizontal lines of data points could be in a random pattern instead of being evenly spaced like now. But I would be glad to get somewhere with this "simple" case first.

Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: +1 This is a classic problem of interpolating data that are obtained along transects.  One standard solution is to use a local neighborhood search routine that reaches out into neighboring transects.

Comment: "In the long term I would like the solution to be applicable to a data set that is even more unordered, i.e. the horizontal lines of data points could be in a random pattern instead of being evenly spaced like now." This may actually make the problem easier, as more  randomly distributed points would give better coverage of the input space. You might want to refocus the question on this if it's closer to your actual interest

Comment: It sounds like you went from a isotopic RBF kernel and then an ARD RBF kernel. You will solve the first problem if you try a full RBF (ie where the length scale is a hermitian matrix, rather than a diagonal matrix or a scalar).